# Merge Profiles option of Contact Form validation rejects https:// urls in profile fields

Tags: bug, status-completed, merge-accounts, ssl, contact

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the "Contact Us" page at https://stackoverflow.com/contact
2. Select "I need to merge user profiles"
3. The autofilled profile URL may be `https://`, in which case it will be throw a validation error on submission, like:

> Error: "your profile link should be of the form `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<display-name>"`

Obviously this also occurs if you manually paste a https link, which is overwhelmingly likely if you're security conscious or using the HTTPS Everywhere plugin.

I would hope it's just an overly aggressive validation pattern, since there's no functional difference I can tell between the 2 profile pages.

Comment: The transition to fully support ssl is on-going but not finished AFAIK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.3.31.2103` on meta and `2014.3.31.1502` on sites.